# An error when I attempt to add search bar to my UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

This is my code:

I am using NSMutableArray:

```
var BusinessNamesArray: NSMutableArray = []
```

And in my viewDidLoad()

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("Category").queryEqualToValue(titlestring)
        .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSMutableDictionary{
                print("print \(dict)")
                for (key,value) in dict {
                    let mainDict = NSMutableDictionary()
                    mainDict.setObject(key, forKey: "userid")

                    if let dictnew = value as? NSMutableDictionary{

                        if let metname = dictnew["BusinessName"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "BusinessName")
                        }
                        if let metname = dictnew["ShortDescription"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "ShortDescription")
                        }
                    }
                    self.BusinessNamesArray.addObject(mainDict)
                }
                print("arrayt is \(self.BusinessNamesArray)")
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
}
```

Table View data source:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BusinessCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let name = BusinessNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{
        cell.textLabel?.text = name["BusinessName"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = name["ShortDescription"] as? String
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    return cell
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
        let detailsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProjectDetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController

        if let name = self.BusinessNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{

            detailsViewController.self.strUserid = name["userid"] as? String
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true)
}
}
```

This is what it looks like when build it:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzDz2.png)

I am trying to add a searchBar programmatically to the UITableView, I followed this tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) and it worked on the starter project which is in the tutorial, but when I try it on my project: in this line `var filteredBusinesses: NSMutableArray = [BusinessNamesArray]` it give me this error: *instance member 'BusinessNamesArray' cannot used on type 'SpecificCategoryTablrVC'*

Any one know what's the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: You could follow a tutorial such as this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

Comment: Sorry, but I'm so beginner, I can't apply that on my project.

Comment: You can, it's a beginner tutorial.

Comment: Ok, I can do it on the starter project in the tutorial, but not on mine.

Comment: You can do the tutorial and then attempt to apply it to your app; then if you have specific problems, edit your question and someone may be able to help.

Comment: I am following the tutorial, but I don't know what should I write in this line: `var filteredCandies = [Candy]()` instead of Candy.

Comment: That's the data source, I guess for you that would be `BusinessNamesArray `, correct?

Comment: When I try it, it give this error: instance member 'BusinessNamesArray' cannot used on type 'SpecificCategoryTablrVC'